# Highcharts stock-chart y-axis values go over 100%

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts line-chart and compare the series as percentages. I want the values to adapt between 0% and 100%, but currently, it goes way over 100%. The orange *odometer* line should be at 100%. Stackoverflow wants me to add more text to post this question, but I dont think this can be explained more in detail. I just hope anyone has had some experience with the same thing and can help me out. Thanks in advance!

[image: example]

EDIT2: Example of a solution I'm after

[image: desired]

See my code example of chart configuration. This is what I have tried so far.

```
return {
  time: {
    timezoneOffset: currentTimeZoneOffset
  },
  chart: {
    redraw: false,
    zoomType: this.rangeEnabled ? 'x' : null,
    type: 'spline',
    alignTicks: false,
    styledMode: true
  },
  title: {
    text: this.title
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      compare: this.showByPercent ? 'percent' : undefined,
      compareBase: 100
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    opposite: false,
    labels: {
      reserveSpace: true
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    // min: 0,
    minRange: 1,
    allowDecimals: false
    // ceiling: 100
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: this.rangeEnabled,
    selected: 0,
    allButtonsEnabled: true,
    buttons: [
      {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w'
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 3,
        text: '3m'
      },
      {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
      },
      {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
      }
    ]
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: this.navigatorEnabled,
    adaptToUpdatedData: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: this.navigatorEnabled,
    scrollbar: {
      liveRedraw: false
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    split: false,
    xDateFormat: this.preciseTooltipDate ? undefined : '%A, %b %e, %Y'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: this.legendEnabled,
    title: { text: 'Filters' },
    // layout: 'vertical',
    // align: 'bottom',
    // verticalAlign: 'middle',
    useHTML: true,
    floating: false
  },
  exporting: {
    // allowHTML: true,
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        enabled: this.download,
        symbol: 'download'
      }
    }
  },
  series: series
};
```

//EDIT: changed line-chart to stock-chart

Comment: Hi @raulicious, Could you reproduce your problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/b45hznp8/

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi, I created a similar scenario here: https://jsfiddle.net/ruq56vt8/3/
Idea would be so it would not go over the chart border, but adapts in the 0% - 100% area.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Highcharts does not provide `compare` and `compareBase` API properties.</strike> You should try to use `'percent'` stacking or `compareBase` with 0 value.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fzmpc37h/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.stacking

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.compare

On the link above it has compare and compareBase. The stacking doesn't give the desired result unfortunately. The blue line is constantly on top and seems to be 100%, but the value is actually changing. So I would expect it to begin from lower percentages and go up accordingly, but not over 100. I'm aware I might have not given the best jsfiddle to describe my problem..

Comment: I added an image of the desired solution to my original post

Comment: @raulicious, Sorry, you are right, `compare` and `compareBase` are provided by Highstock. Maybe, you should try `compareBase` with `0` value (https://jsfiddle.net/o69v3xhL/)? The result depends on the data, so it does not always have to be 100%. You can create an algorithm that will pre-process data in the way you want.